# Why can't I access to my pgAdmin servers?

Tags: terminal, pgadmin-4

When I try to access to my servers on pgAdmin, it not working. I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDZlB.png)t continues to load without stops

I tried to recharge it by my terminal with a code that chatgpt gave me but it doesn't work because my terminal doesn't find the command.

Comment: With that little info you provide it's hard to tell. I'm halfway sure that there is no programming question involved though, it seem to rather be a problem with existing software, making this Q off-topic here. Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask].